# Creating a New PHP Project from GIT in Zend Studio 9

Tags: php, git, zend-studio

I am having a problem while trying to create a new PHP Project from GIT, using Zend Studio 9. I have been able to create projects from GIT in the past with this version of Zend Studio, but the problem with creating this particular project, is with the GIT Repository url...

Let's say my GIT repo url is: 
**git@mydomain.beanstalkapp.com:/my-project.git**

..and the login credentials are: **myname** / pass1234

Now when you go to enter the repo credentials in the *"Creating a New PHP Project from GIT"* popup in Zend Studio, the beginning of the *"Location url"* field, and the *"Authentication User"* field are linked together, meaning if you change the value in one, then Zend automatically changes the other for you. (So anything before the @ sign in the url prepopulates the user field text,and vice versa.)

Now the repository url is only available via SSH, not HTTP, so the url has to start with **git@**... and the user name is not "**git**", so i am effectively unable to add the repository, because zend is not letting me properly fill in user field with a value other than "git".

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git in front of the @ is just the user name. It can be anything, as long as the server is setup to accept it.

To access a git repo over SSH, you need to setup the server to use the SSH identity of the developer. It's basically is the same setup as you would do for a password-less login.

For a good explanation on how to setup a server: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: I had already set up SSH keys to access over SSH. I was having no trouble connecting to the repository with the credentials via command line, but was just stumped when Zend wouldn't let me change the username.

Turns out, with the SSH keys set up, I could leave the username as "git", with an empty password field, and clone the repo with no problems in Zend.

Thanks for the help!